# How to right align a page with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: html, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have a page that is written in RTL in html it is ok but after the conversion
with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) it is centered.

How can I tell wkhtmltopdf to align that page to the right?

For headers and footers there is an option for that, but how to do it for the body?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post your sources somewhere so it would be a bit easier to test?

Have you tried using CSS for the text aligns? Try doing a few tests with simple html files that have paragarphs with the following CSS rules for example:

```
.rtl {
    direction: rtl; 
    text-align: right;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override; 
}

.ltr {
    direction: ltr; 
    text-align: left;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

The CSS rules are taken from an answer by @ThinkingStiff what I would imagine would be the solution or at least very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787780/694325