# javascript variable placeholders for arabic language and numerals "RTL results"

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to edit html using javascript statement that includes numeral variable concatenated with arabic string
this is an example for my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="example"></p>
<script>
var x = "متر ";
var y = 5;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y + x;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the result that I want is the var `y` before the var `x` so it would show as rtl but im always getting it as ltr

i really hope that i explained the issue properly
any help?

Comment: this is because arabic is written from the right to the left?^^

Comment: use `dir="rtl"` in your `<p>` tag and change `y+x` to `x+y` moreover, your `id="example"` so `getElementById("demo")` is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use text-align smartly (if english dir=ltr if arabic dir=rtl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787351/use-text-align-smartly-if-english-dir-ltr-if-arabic-dir-rtl)

Comment: There are many answers already available on SO. So please search before you post a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that was required but everybody answered only part one of many.

- **Step 1 -** You cannot have the multilingual characters in unicode document.. convert the document to **`UTF-8`** document

> advanced editors don't make it simple for you... go low level... 
>   use notepad to save the document as meName.html & change the encoding
>  
>   type to UTF-8

- **Step 2 -** Mention in your html page that you are going to use such characters by

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  ```
- **Step 3 -** When you put in some characters make sure your container tags have the following 2 properties set

  ```
  dir='rtl'
  lang='ar'
  ```
- **Step 4 -** Get the characters from some specific tool\editor or online editor like i did with [Arabic-Keyboard.org](http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/editor/)

**example**

```
<div dir="rtl" lang="ar" style="color:#e0e0e0;font-size:20px;">رَبٍّ زِدْنٍي عِلمًا</div>
```

**NOTE:** font type, font family, font face setting will have no effect on special characters